# Is there a way to push git lfs to bare repository

Tags: git, repository, push, git-lfs, bare

**Describe the issue**
cannot push to the bare repository

I'm new to git, and I don't know if my operation is right.

1. create a bare repo in computer A, and install lfs, and then share the folder to the local network
2. clone the bare repo to computer B and install lfs, track the files using `git lfs track "*.psd"`
3. `git add .` and `git commit -m 'lfs setup'`
4. make some changes to psd files
5. `git add .` and `git commit -m 'some changes'`
6. `git push origin master`

And then... ...

```
$ git push
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (4/4), 46 MB | 0 B/s, done.
EOF
error: failed to push some refs to '<bare repo path>'
```

I don’t know if there is such a way that can fix the problem？

**Output of `git lfs env`**

git lfs env in bare repo:

```
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)
git version 2.31.1.windows.1

LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=<bare repo path>
LocalGitStorageDir=<bare repo path>
LocalMediaDir=<bare repo path>\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=<bare repo path>\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=<bare repo path>\lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

git lfs env in the working repo (non bare)：

```
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.16.2; git a5e65851)
git version 2.31.1.windows.1

Endpoint=file:///<bare repo path> (auth=none)
LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=D:\lfs-repo\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=D:\lfs-repo\.git
LocalMediaDir=D:\lfs-repo\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=D:\lfs-repo\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=D:\lfs-repo\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

Answer (score 1):

Git LFS supports local `file` URLs and can push objects to and from a local repository, but it doesn't currently handle the Windows SMB path syntax.  That's because none of the core developers use that functionality and nobody has sent a patch to implement it.

The next release of Git LFS, 3.0.0, should handle it correctly if you assign the SMB share a drive letter, and it will also support a connection over SSH if you install a suitable server on the remote side.  The former is already available in the `main` branch and the latter will be soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the existing issue with Windows SMB paths. I was banging my head against this particular wall for a couple of hours now.

Answer (score 0):

Git LFS is an extension to Git, it is not part of git itself. It is basically a HTTP server which stores the large files, while only metadata gets pushed to the repository. The LFS server API is documented [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/main/docs/api#readme).

If you want to work with a local bare repository, you can use [lfs-test-server](https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server) to be a local LFS server. **It is only supposed to be used for testing purposes and is NOT PRODUCTION READY**. If you need a production-ready LFS server, you should look into self-hosting a Gitlab or Gitea instance (they can be hosted on your local machine if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and as @bk2204 pointed out, it was an issue with the SMB paths.

[image]

I was ultimately able to resolve it with the information available from [this github issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4391#issuecomment-771844440).
I added an .lfsconfig file with the following content into the root directory of my local repository and pushed it before I pushed the actual LFS files:

```
[lfs]
    url = file:////<ip_of_server>/<path_to_directory>
```

Note **the `file:////` prefix**, that's the important part - using `//` won't work.